# How to register a broadcastreceiver in a custom TextView

Tags: android

I want to get a BroadcastReceiver working in a custom textview . I used this code but nothing is being received.However the setText("ready for receiving") is working properly.

```
public class ArefinBatteryTextView extends TextView {
    private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            setText("received");
        }
    };

   public ArefinBatteryTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

public ArefinBatteryTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    setTextSize(75);
    setText("Ready for receiving");

    LocalBroadcastManager lbm =       LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
    lbm.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}

public ArefinBatteryTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);


}

protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);


}


}
```

How to register the receiver correctly to get it working ?

Comment: "I want to get a BroadcastReceiver working in a custom textview" -- IMHO, whatever activity is responsible for the `TextView` should be responsible for the `BroadcastReceiver`. You may wish to consider learning more about UI architecture patterns (MVC, MVP, MVVM, etc.); a `TextView` should not be responsible for updating itself based upon model changes (battery levels, in this case).

Comment: You have to register a broadcastReceiver inside Your activity not inside a view.

Answer (score 0):

IMO code you are writing is little strange. View Shouldnt hold Logic in MVC Architecture .. View is just for viewing purpose.. View Controller can change values for the view. So kindly use TextView as it is and define your broadcast receiver in Activity (Controller) And than set the values.
I believe I am not confusing you here
http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

Dont know why you guys think this to be impossible but I have done it .This is done like this.

```
public ArefinBatteryTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    setTextSize(75);
    setText("Ready for receiving");

   context.registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
       @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
           int a = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,0);
           setText(""+a);
       }
   }, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}
```